# Do something if AsyncTask is cancelled?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I'm using AsyncTask to populate SQLite database. I'm downloading data from a certain webpage and putting it in SQLite tables. The thing is, I want to either download 100% of the data or none. So in case the AsyncTask is for some reason interrupted, I want to delete all the data that has been downloaded so far.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    dbHandler.deleteFromDatabase(razred);
    Log.i("TAG", "AsyncTask cancelled");
}
```

I thought that "onCancelled" will execute if AsyncTask is interrupted in any way but it doesn't. What could I do to erase data that was made with AsyncTask in case it is cancelled in any way? (ex. activity paused, activity destroyed, internet connection interrupted etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but in your `doInBackground()` you also need to specifically call `isCancelled()` to check if it's cancelled and then return from `doInBackground()`. Then your code will work properly.

Refer to the [`AsyncTask` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for "Cancelling a task"

Here's the quote from the documentation for easy reference:

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean)`. Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` to return true. After invoking this method, `onCancelled(Object)`, instead of `onPostExecute(Object)` will be invoked after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])`, if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

EDIT: Per request, some sample code:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // any kind of initialization or setup needed before the
        //     background thread kicks off. remember: this is still on
        //     on the main (UI) thread

        // since youre doing DB I/O, Ill make believe Im initializing the DB here
        db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(MainActvity.this).getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /*
     * The background thread to do your disk and network I/O. If you need
     * to pass in any parameters, this is the first Void in the template
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // other stuff you need to do in the background. Since you want an
        //   all-or-nothing type thing, we will use a transaction to manually
        //   control the db
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // do network I/O to retrieve what you need and then write to DB.
            ...
            ... // if theres a loop in here somewhere when reading the data, check !isCancelled() as part of the condition or as one of the first statements and then break
            ...
            db.setTransactionSuccessful(); // assuming everything works, need to set
                                         // this successful here at the end of the try
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) { // or some other exception
            cancel(true); // heres where you can call cancel() if youve been interrupted
        } catch (IOException ioe) { // if your network connection has problems
            cancel(true);
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            // other cleanup, like closing the HTTP connection...
            //   no need to close the DB if you implement it properly
        }
        return null; // if there was some return value, that would go here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
        // depending on how you implement doInBackground(), you may not even need this,
        //    unless you have a lot of other "state" you need to reset aside from the DB transaction
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // any other items to do on main (UI) thread after doInBackground() finishes
        //   remember, this only gets called if cancel() is not called!
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way you could show me some sample code on how to do this? It's a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is not exactly what you've asked for, but** I have to say you are doing it all wrong by using the AsyncTask.

There are many cases where your async task will be *terminated* without you being able to do anything. For such critical tasks as this one, use a *Service*.

**With a Service** you can till the system to restart your service in case it is terminated prematurely. You then can continue what you started, or start all over again (deleting all previous downloads...etc).

**With an AsyncTask**, if the system decided to terminate your async task prematurely, you are not notified nor the AsyncTask is restarted. It just dies in complete silence.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the onpostexecute you could handle anything you wanted to.

```
   private class ParseDownload extends AsyncTask<Summary, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Summary... urls) {


        for (Summary url : urls) {
            url.dosomething();
                    if (isCanceled();) { return false;}
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {

                            // delete * from yourtable here...
                            // and mark the download incomplete etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck